# AS2 Load Image to Multiple MC

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

How can I load the same image in to multiple mc's without have to load for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Check [duplicateMovieClip()](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary194.html) and [attachMovie()](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary508.html)